# Django REST API endpoint for specific url

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Im trying to create an endpoint for a post and its comments in the following format:

```
/posts (view all posts)
/posts/{id} (view post by id)
/posts/{id}/comments (view comments for a post)
```

The first 2 work, but for the last one I have `/comments` rather than the url i would like and I am not sure how to go about that, I think I need to change my models for it.

My current models (its using default Django User):

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class PostComment(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comment = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.post.title
```

And urls:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)
router.register(r'posts', views.PostViewSet)
router.register(r'comments', views.PostCommentViewSet)
```

Edit: this are the viewsets

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all().order_by('id')
    serializer_class = UserSerializer


class PostViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Post.objects.all().order_by('created_at')
    serializer_class = PostSerializer


class PostCommentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = PostComment.objects.all().order_by('created_at')
    serializer_class = PostCommentSerializer
```

Comment: can you add the `PostViewSet` class?

Comment: I had post view sets, i added them in the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by writing the [custom viewset actions--(drf doc)](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing),

```
from rest_framework.decorators import action
from rest_framework.response import Response


class PostViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Post.objects.all().order_by('created_at')
    serializer_class = PostSerializer

    @action(detail=True, url_path='comments', url_name='post-comments')
    def comments(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = PostComment.objects.filter(post=kwargs['pk'])
        serializer = PostCommentSerializer(queryset, many=True, context= {'request':request, 'view':self})
        return Response(data=serializer.data)
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this, I get this error: `HyperlinkedIdentityField` requires the request in the serializer context. Add `context={'request': request}` when instantiating the serializer.

Answer (score 1):

Your view should be something similar to this -

```
class PostCommentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = PostComment.objects.all().order_by('created_at')
    serializer_class = PostCommentSerializer

    @action(detail=True)
    def comments(self, request, id=None):
        ....
```

You can refer to DRF documentation for more detail here - https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#routing-for-extra-actions

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the router, then this is probably achievable by implementing a custom router, like in this example: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#example

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to register the viewset route parameters with the action decorator

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing

it should work if you had in your viewset

```
from rest_framework.decorators import action

@actions(detail=True)
def comments(self, request, pk):
  # things to do here
```